# changing the data type of Formula field salesforce

Tags: salesforce, type-conversion

Hi I have tried to change the data type of formula field but we cannot as per salesforce standard limitations. so i have created a new field  and used . Now if i delete the formula field then the  existing data in the formula field  also will be loose or is there any way for me to get the data into text field newly created.

Comment: Can you show us some code? It's hard to tell what you're actually asking without a chunk of code.

Comment: Sory I am not using any code in my requirement . If i delete any formula field. what would be the existing data of that field.

Comment: Please, read this: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ and then try to edit the question, so that we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't that clear but I'm guessing you can execute a code anonymously using developer console. The code would copy the data from formula field to the newly created text field; and update records.